# Reloading data from a tableView within a collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uitableview

I have a `tableView` inside a `collectionViewCell` and I get an error when I try to reload the data.

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UITableView.m:1610
```

I tried using `Dispatch.main.async` and it seems to get rid of the problem. The only thing is that it doesn't reload the data and nothing changes in the `tableView`

```
func cleanItems(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    Dispatch.main.async {

        cell.tableView.beginUpdates()
        // Make changes in the Data Source
        cell.tableView.deleteRows(at: selectedItems, with: .fade)
        cell.tableView.endUpdates()

        // Reloading sections accordingly depending on what the user has deleted

        // Do I need to reload data here again? It used to work without Dispatch, but it wasn't stable
        cell.tableView.reloadData()


        // Updating items with if statements to reload data in Firebase

        completion(true)

    }
}
```

This doesn't reload the data at all and nothing seems to change. The good thing is that I don't get a random crash, which was the case before implementing `Dispatch.main.async`

I've retrieved the `numberOfRows` in each section to see how many rows there are after ending updates.

```
print(cell.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 1))
```

and I get the same number of rows that are in the current view.

This is crucial, because if the `tableView` sections are all zero, the `collectionViewCell` should disappear. And we never get here in the `completion` block as it says that the `numberOfRows` has never changed. Leaving us with a non updated `tableView`.

Comment: You need to also delete object from your array also.

Comment: I've done that in the actual code, I've just simplified the structure here. The way I do it is to get the selectedIndexPaths and apply a filter to delete the items at the selectedIndexPaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by moving `Dispatch.main.async` outside the function call.

```
Dispatch.main.async {

    cleanItems(completion: { (success) in 


    etc.


    })

}
```